# How does this Power Series represent this function? My numbers don't come close.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{4x+1}$$

I watched some video that resulted in the following.  It creates the geometric series using the series sum formula of $\frac{1}{1-r}$

$f(x)=\frac{x}{4x+1} = (x)(\frac{1}{1+4x}) = (x)(\frac{1}{1-(-4x)}) = (x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-4x)^n = (x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-4)^nx^n = $

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-4)^nx^{n+1} $$

This power series does not appear to approximate $f(x)=\frac{x}{4x+1}$ in any fashion whatsoever.

For example, $f(7) = \frac{7}{29} = .24$

That power series yields massive numbers that are nothing line .24.
Where is the error here??

Comment: The geometric series only converges for $\lvert r \rvert < 1$. For any other $r$, $r^n$ diverges as you have evidently observed.

Comment: Are you ok with the expansion $g(x)=\frac 1{1-x}=\sum x^n$ ?  That doesn't come close at $x=7$ either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This representation holds for $|4x|<1\iff -0.25<x<0.25$. (remember that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$).

Comment: Ahh, I forgot about the stipulation of domain.